# How to fix: Slow Wordpress admin load time for some admins while good for other admins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have wordpress 4.9.8
The Load time of pages after logging-in is fine for my user. But when I log in with other users to the WP-ADMIN (also configured as admins) it is VERY SLOW (1-2 minutes to move between pages).

I tested it on the same PC and Browser. So definitely a user level problem.
Both users configured the same. Both are admins.

I tried all "WP-ADMIN slow" solutions on the web and none fixed that. Disabled every possible plugin (cache, fence...)

How could that happen? How can I fix this?

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to go off of here. How much CPU usage are those users taking up, what are the server response times like for them, are there issues with your hosting service (using EIG hosting is never recommended), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up and optimize your database (backup first!).

Try to limit heartbeat with heartbeat plugin (heartbeat is always using ajax to update admin widgets, save drafts, etc and it can be intensive).

Install Query Monitor plugin to find out plugins and database queries that are slowing down the back end.

Answer (score 0):

I try many things and finally I already solved it just remove your pending cron (ROOT CAUSE)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'cron';
```